# How to handle authentication post-signup with Passport.js

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, passport.js, passport-local

I'm struggling with understanding how authentication with Passport works. I'm using Express.js as my routing management package and I have 3 usable routes and one router :

```
routes
├── auth.endpoints.js
├── concept.endpoints.js
├── routes.js
└── user.endpoints.js
```

`routes.js` is my API gateway, handling traffic to the different routes and it looks like this :

```js
const { isConnected } = require("../middleware/is.connected"); //middleware that checks whether req.user exists or not

module.exports = function (app, passport) {
  const userRouter = require("./user.endpoints");
  const authRouter = require("./auth.endpoints")(passport);
  const conceptRouter = require("./concept.endpoints");
  const logger = require("../log/winston.logger");
  const logLevels = require("../log/log.levels.json").levels;
  app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    logger(req.method + " " + req.url, logLevels.http);
    next();
  });
  app.use("/auth", authRouter);
  app.use(isConnected);
  app.use("/api/user", userRouter);
  app.use("/api/concept", conceptRouter);
};
```

The issue is in the `auth` route, more precisely, the signup endpoint :

```js
// @ts-nocheck
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const { isConnected } = require("../middleware/is.connected");
const ErrorMiddleware = require("../middleware/error.middleware");
const { isAValidInstance } = require("../utils/schema.validator");
const userSchema = require("../database/schemas/user.schema.json");
const User = require("../database/models/user.model");
const logger = require("../log/winston.logger");
const SHA256 = require("js-sha256");
const logLevels = require("../log/log.levels.json").levels;
const ResponseError = require("../responses/response.error");
const ResponseSuccess = require("../responses/response.success");
module.exports = function (passport) {
  router.get(
    "/logout",
    isConnected,
    ErrorMiddleware(function (req, res, next) {
      req.logout();
      res.clearCookie("connect.sid", {
        path: "/",
      });
      // eslint-disable-next-line node/handle-callback-err
      req.session.destroy(function (err) {
        ResponseSuccess.success(res);
      });
    })
  );

  router.post(
    "/login",
    passport.authenticate("local", {
      successRedirect: "/auth/me",
      failureRedirect: "/login",
    })
  );

  router.get(
    "/me",
    isConnected,
    ErrorMiddleware((req, res, next) => {
      ResponseSuccess.success(res, req.user);
    })
  );

  router.post(
    "/signup",
    ErrorMiddleware(async (req, res, next) => {
      if (req.user !== undefined) {
        res.redirect("/me");
        return;
      }
      const user = req.body;
      if (!isAValidInstance(user, userSchema)) {
        logger("POST /auth/signup", logLevels.warn, "Invalid body");
        ResponseError.badRequest(res);
        return;
      }
      user.password = SHA256(user.password);
      const createdUser = await User.createUser(user);
      if (createdUser !== null) {
        ResponseSuccess.success(res, createdUser);
      } else {
        ResponseError.unauthorized(res);
      }
    })
  );
  return router;
};
```

The problem is that after I sign up, I still have to manually login (at least via the backend and Postman) in order to be considered authenticated.

Is there something wrong with the way I'm doing things?

FYI, this is my current passport configuration :

```js
// @ts-nocheck
const passport = require("passport");
const User = require("../database/models/user.model");
const SHA256 = require("js-sha256");
const LocalStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy;
const session = require("express-session");

module.exports = function (app) {
  passport.use(
    new LocalStrategy(
      {
        usernameField: "email",
        passwordField: "password",
      },
      async (email, password, done) => {
        const user = await User.findUser(email, SHA256(password));
        if (user == null) {
          return done(null, false);
        }
        return done(null, user.user_id);
      }
    )
  );

  passport.serializeUser((userId, done) => {
    return done(null, userId);
  });
  passport.deserializeUser(async function (userId, done) {
    const user = await User.getUserByUserId(userId);
    return done(null, user);
  });
  app.use(
    session({ secret: "anything", resave: false, saveUninitialized: false })
  );
  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(passport.session());

  return passport;
};
```

I feel like the serialisation isn't working correctly.

Many thanks in advance for your help!